# User defined class that holds exception

Tags: c++, class, exception

I am new to exceptions and I am supposed to use a class to hold the exception if the index of an array is negative. I am having trouble implementing the data for the defined function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "IntergerArray.h"
using namespace std;
OutOfBoundException index(int);
int main()
{    
    try
    {
        int SIZE;
        cout << "Enter index: ";
        cin >> SIZE;
        IntArray table(SIZE);
        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
            table[x] = x;

        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
            cout << table[x] << " ";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    catch (string exceptionString)
    {
        cout << exceptionString << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
OutOfBoundException index(int SIZE)
{
    if (SIZE < 0) 
    {
        string exceptionString = "ERROR";
        throw exceptionString;
    }
    return index(SIZE);
}
```

I have a feeling that it is not returning the exception when it is called whenever there is a negative input. The program crashes when there is a negative number. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range).

Comment: Your `index` function calls itself when `SIZE >= 0`.

Comment: When called with non-negative argument, `index()` is infinitely recursive.   It will never return since (notionally at least) it will keep calling itself forever.

Comment: @Peter I wasn't entirely sure what I could return since I wasn't returning an operation which a lot of exceptions are used for. That is why I put index(). How could I have the exception return in order for it to be caught? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Your question confuses me because this doesn't sound like "using a class to hold the exception" - in that case I would expect the exception type to be an object like `std::out_of_range`, but here it seems to be a `string`. Did I misunderstand, or is it possible that this code is doing the wrong thing in that regard?

Comment: @BenS. I apologize. I am using a object function to hold the exception. I am using a string to display "ERROR" whenever the index inputted is out of range

Comment: A function returns (in the sense of returning control to the immediate caller) or it throws an exception (which propagates up the call stack until it is caught, or -if not caught - causes program termination).   A function might return in some conditions and throw exceptions in others, but an exception does not return.

Comment: @GhostCat sorry I deleted it because I figured out what i was looking for. Also got down voted for some reason so I had no wish to keep it up. I was typing fast and missed the two == btw my bad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad you found out ...

Comment: And while looking at this question: keep in mind that all messages that your code gives should be helpful. "ERROR" ... what does that help. Why not "Cant create exception for negative size: " + size value?!